# making an angular service for a rootscope promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-services, angularjs-http

I'm trying to ensure that upon loading the `frame` state, that my `$rootScope` has all the necessary properties defined from previous states.

The `ionic.utils` module is properly injected into my angular app. This module comes from my **services.js** file.

```
angular.module('ionic.utils', [])
.factory('dataService', ['$rootScope','$q','$timeout', function($rootScope, $q, $timeout) {
    return {
        get: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function() {
              deferred.resolve($rootScope);
            }, 2000);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Inside my **controllers.js** file, this is the corresponding controller for my `frame` state:

```
.controller('FrameCtrl', ['$scope','$state','$rootScope','dataService',
function($scope, $state, $rootScope, dataService) {
    // get active address and delivery time.
    dataService.get().success(function() {
        console.log("derp");
    });
}])
```

However, this controller returns the following console error upon state transition:

```
ionic.bundle.js:17696 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (controllers.js:201)
    at invoke (ionic.bundle.js:11591)
    at Object.instantiate (ionic.bundle.js:11602)
    at $get (ionic.bundle.js:14906)
    at updateView (ionic.bundle.js:42986)
    at IonicModule.directive.directive.compile.eventHook (ionic.bundle.js:42933)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$broadcast (ionic.bundle.js:20605)
    at $state.transitionTo.$state.transition.resolved.then.$state.transition (ionic.bundle.js:34122)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (ionic.bundle.js:19197)
    at ionic.bundle.js:19283
```

I'm having trouble finding the error in the service I've written. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
After adding the dependency injections into my controller, now the error has changed. Here it is:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (controllers.js:202)
    at invoke (ionic.bundle.js:11591)
    at Object.instantiate (ionic.bundle.js:11602)
    at $get (ionic.bundle.js:14906)
    at updateView (ionic.bundle.js:42986)
    at IonicModule.directive.directive.compile.eventHook (ionic.bundle.js:42933)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$broadcast (ionic.bundle.js:20605)
    at $state.transitionTo.$state.transition.resolved.then.$state.transition (ionic.bundle.js:34122)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (ionic.bundle.js:19197)
    at ionic.bundle.js:19283
```

Comment: `angular.module('ionic.utils', [])
.factory('dataService', ['$rootScope','$q','$timeout', function($rootScope, $q, $timeout) {
    return {
        get: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function() {
              return deferred.resolve($rootScope);
            }, 2000);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}]);`

controller should be `dataService.get().then(function() {
        console.log("derp");
    });`

Comment: I'm not sure what you posted the service implementation for...But I managed to catch that `.then()` call. That seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally with promises we just use `.then`, which takes the success function as the first parameter and the error function as the second.

> `success` and `error` are functions on a promise that AngularJS adds
>   for us when using `$http` or $resource. They're not standard, you
>   won't find them on other promises.

**Code**

```
dataService.get().then(function() { 
    console.log("derp"); 
});
```

Return was missing from `deferred.resolve()`

```
 angular.module('ionic.utils', []).factory('dataService', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$timeout', function($rootScope, $q, $timeout) {
        return {
            get: function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $timeout(function() {
                    return deferred.resolve($rootScope);
                }, 2000);
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Hopefully this will help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your dependency array in controller is missing numerous dependencies passed to arguments

```
.controller('FrameCtrl', [ 'Rootscope', function($scope, $state, 
$rootScope, Rootscope) {
```

Should be

```
.controller('FrameCtrl', ['$scope','$state', '$rootScope', 'Rootscope', function($scope, $state, 
    $rootScope, Rootscope) {
```

Sure seems confusing to me to name a service `Rootscope`!

Comment: Still an error -__- That definitely helped some though! Changed the name of it to dataService for now, till I think of a better name.